# JavaFX display image in WebView from external directory

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, webview, javafx

I have a WebView and a Javascript that appends an `<img>` tag in a webview.

Like so:

```
function insertImg(src) {
   $("body").append("<img src='" + src + "'/>");
}
```

I call this function with the following code:

`webengine.executeScript("insertImg('" + path + "')");`

The path string is the path to an image somewhere in the user's HD.

If the PATH string is, for instance, an image in the directory /User/mac/Pictures (which is not in the jar's directory), the image is not displayed in the webview.

I suspect I have to preload this image in Java before JavaFX's webview can load it. How can this be done?

Thanks in advance.